# determine programs installed on linux

Tags: linux

Is there a way to compare which programs are currently installed on my linux box compared to the stock versions?  I need to recreate my current setup for another computer, and have installed many little command line programs that I can't remember everything that all of my own python scripts depend on - for example xdotool and xprintidle.  If I try my python scripts on a computer without them, they just fail since the programs don't exist.  Is there a way to get a list of all of these programs other than simply running each of my python programs until they fail?

Comment: In order to have a chance of answering this, you'll need to specify which distribution of Linux you are using.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu linux

Comment: In that case, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages

Answer (score 0):

The best command is

```
sudo dpkg -l
```

It produces a lot of output, so careful. It shows the package version and the architecture, neither of which are shown by dpkg --get-selections. Also, it allows searches:

```
sudo dpkg -l *xserver*
```

all packages related to X server. But above all, it provides a brief description of each installed package,

```
# dpkg -l 
||/ Name                                  Version                                Architecture Description
+++-=====================================-======================================-============-=============================================================================
ii  accountsservice                       0.6.29-1ubuntu8                        amd64        query and manipulate user account information
ii  acl                                   2.2.51-8ubuntu3                        amd64        Access control list utilities
ii  acpi                                  1.6-1                                  amd64        displays information on ACPI devices
ii  acpi-support                          0.141                                  amd64        scripts for handling many ACPI events
```

which dpkg --get-selections does not provide:

```
# dpkg --get-selections
accountsservice                                 install
acl                                             install
acpi                                            install
acpi-support                                    install
acpid                                           install
adduser                                         install
```

Comment: Correct me, but I think you don't need `sudo` for `dpkg -l`. (It's `/usr/bin/dpkg` not `/usr/sbin/dpkg`)

Comment: You are right, no sudo.